# Jquery : Hide all children, and their children and etc... of a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

I'm making a game in DOM (javascript + jquery) and I need to switch stages, for that I need to hide all from one stage, and show all of a new one. The showing part is easy cuz I'm creating new stuff. But I'd like a clean way of finding every last single child of a div, all his descendance, cousin, niece I don't care, and hide them. To show that in code something like :

```
while (child = $(this).hasChildren)
{
  child.hide();
}
```

Instead of something like that :

```
$(this.id).children().children().children().hide();
$(this.id).children().children().hide();
$(this.id).children().hide()
$(this.id).hide();
```

The goal is to hide his children, and his children's children, and so on.
I hope I'm not too confusing.
Thanks in advance for the answers!

EDIT: for someone that doesn't want to hide the children, but access them all, and you can't use .find("*") then answer number two might be more adapted for you (the one from Rajan Goswami).

Comment: Why don't you just hide the parent ? parent.hide(); ?

Comment: when you hide an element, all children become not visible..

Comment: I answered that under Stoyan Dekov's answer. Long story short : I thought that it didn't.
Does that works with remove by the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to perform something on all children of an element you can use this syntax:

```
$('#myDiv *').hide();
```

or using `.find()`

```
$('#myDiv').find('*').hide();
```

Of course you can use any function, not just `.hide()`

Comment: Much better than recursion.

Comment: Yeah, in fact I thought it didn't work, but that was my fault in fact, did a mistake that led me to believe that perhaps all children weren't hidden automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following solution:

> "myParentControl" is the ID of the parent-most control.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   HideChildren($(#myParentControl))
})

function HideChildren(cntrl){
    if ( $(cntrl).children().length > 0 ) {
         $(cntrl).children().each(function(){
           HideChildren(this);
           $(this).hide();
         })
    }
}
```

Comment: `$(this).hide();` should be outside the if block.

Comment: Thanks, that can come in handy one day when doing something with the parent doesn't do it automatically with the children!

Comment: I am happy that this solution helped you in some way. Please accept this also as an answer. Thank you.